How to make size of rectangle depend on biggest item in a list of items
I have this simple example program with 2 columns. The column on the left holds a datagrid, and the column on the right has a red rectangle in the middle. I want to make a binding, so that the width/height of the rectangle is always equal to the size of the biggest item in the list.
Picture of Main Window:

Picture of Solution explorer:

So far i have this:
MainWindow.xaml
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="300"/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <!-- Left Column -->
    <StackPanel Margin="0 20 0 0">
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" Margin="20 0 20 0"
                  AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                  CanUserResizeColumns="False" CanUserResizeRows="False"
                  CanUserSortColumns="False" CanUserReorderColumns="False"
                  CanUserDeleteRows="False" CanUserAddRows="False"
                  SelectionMode="Single" SelectionUnit="Cell">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <!-- Column 1 - Name -->
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name"
                                    Binding="{Binding Name}"
                                    Width="150">
                </DataGridTextColumn>
                <!-- Column 2 - Size -->
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Size"
                                    Binding="{Binding Size}"
                                    Width="*">
                </DataGridTextColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </StackPanel>

    <!-- Right Column -->
    <Border Grid.Column="1"
            BorderBrush="Black"
            BorderThickness="1">
        <Rectangle Width="{Binding SizeOfRectangle}"
                   Height="{Binding SizeOfRectangle}"
                   Fill="Red">
        </Rectangle>
    </Border>
</Grid>

MainWindow.xaml.cs
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        MainWindowViewModel viewModel = new MainWindowViewModel();
        this.DataContext = viewModel;
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}

Item.cs
public class Item
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double Size { get; set; }
}

MainWindowViewModel.cs
public class MainWindowViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<Item> Items { get; }
    public double SizeOfRectangle { get; set; }

    public MainWindowViewModel() 
    {
        //Initialize list of items:
        Items = new ObservableCollection<Item>()
        {
            new Item { Name = "Item 1", Size = 120 },
            new Item { Name = "Item 2", Size = 150 },
            new Item { Name = "Item 3", Size = 180 },
            new Item { Name = "Item 4", Size = 100 },
            new Item { Name = "Item 5", Size = 225 }
        };

        //Find the biggest size and assign to "SizeOfRectangle"
        double MaxSize = Items[0].Size;
        for (int i = 1; i < Items.Count; i++)
        {
            if (Items[i].Size > MaxSize)
                MaxSize = Items[i].Size;
        }
        SizeOfRectangle = MaxSize; //Width and Height of rectangle bound to this
    }
}

I have initialized a list of 5 items, and made an iteration in the ViewModel which finds the largest size (and sets the height/width of the rectangle to 225 in this case). I want to make it so that when i change the sizes of the items through the datagrid, the program will check if the max size has changed, and the size of the rectangle can change accordingly.
I am expecting I need to make some sort of event, and make use of INotifyPropertyChanged, etc. But currently I am at a bit of a loss as to where to start. I would greatly appreciate any help you can offer.

The problem and solution is very similar to the one in your older question https://stackoverflow.com/q/78707147/1136211. The core point is that the Item class implements INotifyPropertyChanged and MainViewModel attaches a PropertyChanged event handler to each Item. Whenever the Size property of an Item changes, MainViewModel would re-evaluate the value of the SizeOfRectangle property.

The property itself would ideally be written as public double SizeOfRectangle => Items.Select(item => Item.Size).Max();

Something like this would also be an approach: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30486363/1136211. Or this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5796727/1136211

Just use BindingList instead of ObservableCollection.

No need to download a toolkit (like a different answer is suggesting), you just need to implement the interfaces.  I answer the question on how to handle the data grid edit's to Size at the bottom of my answer.
Your View Model should be implementing INotifyPropertyChanged  Then, after you set the SizeOfRectangle you need to trigger the property changed event so that the binding will refresh.  All view models must implement this interface otherwise the initial get on the vm properties will never update.  After reading your question a few times it's clear that you know this.
So add the event and these 2 helper methods after you extend the class
// implementing the INotifyPropertyChanged interface
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };

// add some helper methods to fire the property changed.
public virtual void TriggerPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
{
   this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}

protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string propertyName = "")
{
        this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}

I always code my properties of a vm using real backend vars..  but your code (if left as-is) would just need to change your existing code like below (after you add the code I posted above):
//Find the biggest size and assign to "SizeOfRectangle"
double MaxSize = Items[0].Size;
for (int i = 1; i < Items.Count; i++)
{
   if (Items[i].Size > MaxSize)
      MaxSize = Items[i].Size;
}
 
SizeOfRectangle = MaxSize; //Width and Height of rectangle bound to this
TriggerPropertyChanged("SizeOfRectagle"); // update the view

This is how you should code vm properties going forward:
private double _Size;
public double SizeOfRectangle 
{ get  { return _Size; }
  set
  {
     if (_Size != value)
     {
          _Size = value;
          OnPropertyChanged();  //call this method without 
                                //having to specify the property.  
                      //The methods [CallerMemberName] will handle at compile time.
     }
  }
}

You are correctly using the ObserrvableCollection<Item> however your Item class is not a "real view model".  Won't be a problem until you start binding to properties to the Item.  You should always dedicate view models and avoid using Domain level classes as view models.
To automatically update the SizeOfRectangle do the following:
Implement the INotifyPropertyChanged on Item class and add those 2 helper methods just like you did in the MainViewModel class.
Your Item class needs to be able to signal the SizeOfRectangle when the Size property is changed. So add a reference to the MainViewModel in the Item.
public class Item : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    ...

    public MainViewModel  MainViewModel  { get; set; }  

 }

So when you create an Item instance set the property (set Size last):
new Item { Name = "Item 1",  MainViewModel = this, Size = 120 }

You could always make the MainViewModel implement some interface that updates the SizeOfRectangle if you were concerned with reuse and didn't want to hard code a VM in the Item class, but for this example we will just use the MainViewModel itself.
Then change the Item setter and use a backend prop:
private double _Size;
public double Size {
    get {
       return _Size;
    }
    set {
       if ( _Size != value)
       {
           _Size = value;
           if ( MainViewModel!= null && MainViewModel.SizeOfRectangle < _Size)
           {
              MainViewModel.SizeOfRectangle = _Size;
           }
           OnPropertyChanged();

       }
    }
}


There is still no mechanism that would trigger a change of the SizeOfRectangle property when any of the Item objects in the Items collection changes, or when an Item is added to or removed from the collection.

i didn't see that as part of the Q..  i will add, that is easy.

I'd say that is the core of the question. "I want to make it so that when i change the sizes of the items through the datagrid, the program will check if the max size has changed, and the size of the rectangle can change accordingly."

ah.. i was too quick

now it does that.

That is not a particularly great solution. Better attach a PropertyChanged handler to an Item when it is added to the Items collection. You may do that in a CollectionChanged handler that is attached to the Items property.

i advised the OP to implement the INotifyPropertyChanged event + the 2 helper methods.  my solution gives the desired behavior.

Sure, but the reference to the parent view model in the item view model is avoidable. Why should an Item know about the MainViewModel when it isn't necessary?

sure, but when building vm's with many properties my approach is simpler and easier to maintain

Definitely not.

whatever.   it's a simple Q... i answered the Q.

Clemens point is valid if you the OP is going to allow the Grid to add new Item instances on the fly.  in that case sure, i get why.  but if the Item's will be added via code then no need.  The XAML shows CanUserAddRows to false.

My point is the avoidable reference. Avoid anything that is avoidable -> better code.

And for me, my vm's typically need to a lot more business logic and i like that to be in the vm in the property.  i get your point, but i would not change it.

your suggesting adding an event listener of each Item... it's a ref... its no diff.

*business logic  is wrong term, view logic for the vm, rarely put business logic in a vm, but the logic that is in the vm is dedicated to making the view operate correctly.  The SizeOfRectangle is not biz logic, it is view logic.

In order to get notified about changes of their properties, the Item and MainViewModel class need to implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface. In the following code snippet this is done by deriving from the ObservableObject class in the CommunityToolkit.Mvvm package - but it can obviously also be done manually.
Then you could use BindingList instead of ObservableCollection in order to get notified not only when when elements are added to or removed from the collection, but also when they raise their PropertyChanged event.
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;

public partial class Item : ObservableObject
{
    [ObservableProperty]
    private string name;

    [ObservableProperty]
    private double size;
}

public partial class MainViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    public BindingList<Item> Items { get; } = [];

    public double MaxItemSize => Items.Select(item => item.Size).Max();

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        Items.ListChanged += (s, e) => OnPropertyChanged(nameof(MaxItemSize));
    }
}


Wouldn't it be easier to use BindingList instead of ObservableCollection for this task?

@EldHasp Yes, definitely. I changed the answer accordingly.
